# thought little of them

Tags: grammar, quantifiers

Take note of the following sentence:

> Paul Newman himself thought little of them. [[1]](https://www.economist.com/obituary/2008/10/02/paul-newman)

In this sentence, is **"little"** modifying the verb **" thought"** as an adverb or there's something implicit between **"little _____ of"**? I could not understand.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's functioning as an adverb or adverbial phrase. As for what's implied, I would say it's an idiom:

> to think little [of someone] - to not have much respect for or to have a low opinion about someone

Similarly:

> to think less [of someone] - to lower your opinion/have less respect than before

> to think a lot [of someone] - to have a very high opinion of or a lot of respect for someone

> to think more [of someone] - to raise your opinion/have more respect than before

Comment: Thanks, @swmcdonnell! I've searched everywhere but forgot to check idioms ahaha. Take care.

Comment: +1 And it's worth noting this same sentence can mean, "*Paul Newman himself didn't think about them very often.*"

Comment: Thanks for adding more info, go!